# Reactjs ternary not display a return

Tags: reactjs

I have a ternary operator and if-else statement, but the ternary operator is not return anything. There is no error on the console so I assume it was run successfully.

```
renderTags() {
    this.state.tags.length === 0 ? (
      <h3>There are no tags!</h3>
    ) : (
      <ul>
        {this.state.tags.map((tag) => (
          <li key={tag}>{tag}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
    if (this.state.tags.length === 0) {
      <h3>There are no tags!</h3>;
    }
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.tags.map((tag) => (
          <li key={tag}>{tag}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
```

I display it here

```
{this.renderTags()}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the ternary operator, but you aren't doing anything with the result of it (which is why the console doesn't show any errors). It should be:

```
renderTags() {
    return this.state.tags.length === 0 ? (
      <h3>There are no tags!</h3>
    ) : (
      <ul>
        {this.state.tags.map((tag) => (
          <li key={tag}>{tag}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
```